Google Authentication failed in Jetpack compose
I was trying to add google sign in system in my project. I have fulfilled every criteria on API Console. But whenever I select any google account for signing in it sends request code 0. I followed bellow approach.
Google Sign in client
fun getGoogleSignInClient(context: Context): GoogleSignInClient {
    val gso =
        GoogleSignInOptions
            .Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(CLIENT_ID)
            .requestEmail()
            .requestScopes(Scope(Scopes.DRIVE_FILE))
            .build()
    return GoogleSignIn.getClient(context, gso)
}

From where invoking sign in operation
`Row(
                modifier =
                    Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .padding(top = 24.dp)
                        .clickable {
                            val existingAccount = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(context)
                            if (existingAccount != null) {
                                Toast.makeText(context, "Already signed in", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                            } else {
                                val googleSignInClient = getGoogleSignInClient(context)
                                launcher.launch(googleSignInClient.signInIntent)
                            }
                        },
                verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
            )`

Launcher to launch intent
`val launcher =
        rememberLauncherForActivityResult(contract = ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
            val intent = result.data
            println("Result code is ${result.resultCode}")
            if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                if (result.data != null) {
                    val task: Task<GoogleSignInAccount> =
                        GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(intent)
                    if (task.isSuccessful) {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Sign in successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Sign in failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Sign in failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }`


